# Remote Desktop Connection won't connect - Security Package does not exist

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, authentication

Between two Windows 7 Ultimate computers. Worked fine up until about an hour ago. File sharing, web browsing works ok too.

---

### Remote Desktop Connection

An authentication error has occurred.
The requested security package does not exist

Remote Computer: Computer-Name

[OK]

---

I found http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/7698b90a-0708-4aa2-a33b-9734de14319c and discovered that the broken computer was missing those values, but after I restored them, it was still broken.

Thanks

Comment: It is also possible that an issue on the *client* computer gives the "The requested security package does not exist" error. Or at least restarting the 'server' side didn't help, but restarting the client laptop did. Unsure what was wrong, and it was from inside a Windows 11 Sandbox, so environment is now reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution

> HKLM\system\currentcontrolset\control\lsa\security packages

It should have these values: `kerberos msv1_0 schannel wdigest tspkg pku2u`

The `tspkg` and `pku2u` values were missing.

Comment: I mentioned this in my question. All of the computers involved have had Windows reinstalled since I asked so I couldn't try any new answers anyway though.

Comment: The order of these values is very important: I was trying to prevent this (http://www.ampliasecurity.com/research/wcefaq.html#digestauth) from working, and while it did, it also hosed RDP to 2008 boxes; when I re-added wdigest, I had it last and after rebooting, still no dice.

Comment: I'm going to assume this would have worked.